# How to execute a controller private method after a model update?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a private method inside a controller.

```
private
def update_mark
...
...
end
```

- I want my private method to be called whenever record gets updated to any of the four Models we have. How can we do this ?
- I read "after_save" or "after_commit" can be used. But I am not sure, which one to use.

Can someone provide me an example, on how we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your models (let's say A,B) add a method that marks the instance as updated

```
#A
class A < ApplicationRecord

  attr_reader :updated
  after_update :mark_updated

  private
  def mark_updated
     @updated = true
  end
end

#B
class B < ApplicationRecord
  attr_reader :updated
  after_update :mark_updated

  private
  def mark_updated
     @updated = true
  end
end
```

Consume the instance variable which has marked updated In your controller

```
class DummyController < ApplicationController

  #after the action we call the private method    
  after_action :update_mark, only: [:your_method]

  #this is the method where your update takes place
  def your_method
    @instance = klass.find(params[:id])
    @instance.update
  end

  private

  # this is a model decider method which can figure out which model needs to 
  # be updated
  def klass
     case params[:type]
     when 'a'
       A
     when 'b'
       B
     end
  end

  def update_mark
    if @instance.updated
      #write code which needs to run on model update
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: @GokulnathKumar added a `klass` method this is just to decide which model to pick based on params. You can have your own logic on which model class to pick and a single method can take care of it.